# How wealthy were the members/factions of the CIS?

Tags: star-wars

I'm looking for a hard number or even a range of how much money (or credits) the CIS possessed. I expect it to be a vast sum but just how vast of a sum is it?

Comment: Seven.  They were seven wealthy.

Comment: @WadCheber I didn't know the Star Wars galaxy also used the [Trigantic Pu](http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/Triganic_Pu). Very useful fact for the inter-universal hitchhiker.

Comment: Since most were privately held entities, I'm pretty sure the information woldn't have been available in-universe, logically speaking